# Why event not firing (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page, with 2 buttons (each button refer to another page):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TBD</title>      
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="A">A</button>
        <button id="B">B</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#A").click(function(){       
        $.get( "/A.html", function( data ) {
            console.log("A button clicked");
            document.write(data);   
        });

    });

    $("#B").click(function(){       
        $.get( "/B.html", function( data ) {
            console.log("B button clicked");
            document.write(data);   
        });

    });
});
```

A and B (HTMLs and JSs) have the same behavior:
for example  (B.html & B.js):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>B</title>                    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/B.js"></script>      
    </head>

    <body>
        B
        <button id="backButton">Back</button>
    </body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("B js ready");
    $("#backButton").click(function(){      
        console.log("back button clicked");
        $.get( "/back.html", function( data ) {
            console.log("get results");
            document.write(data);   
        });

    });

});
```

I when I clicked from main page  on A or B button and get to the new page,
I can see in the Console log that the A.js (or B.js) are ready (so the A.js or B.js are loaded),
But after it , if I click on the "back" button, nothing happen (even the line `console.log("back button clicked");` is not called.

Why this happen and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your script tag to the end of your html tag, so the page will render before the javascript call.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>B</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    B <button id="backButton">Back</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/B.js"></script> //add script line here!
  </body>
</html>
```

To show the rendering problem, place the script tag right before the head tag and  add a debugger in your B.js file and run the page with the developer tool open.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger; // Add debugger here!
  console.log('B js ready');
  $('#backButton').on('click', function() {
    console.log('back button clicked');
    $.get('/back.html', function(data) {
      console.log('get results');
      document.write(data);
    });
  });
});
```

When you load the page B you will see that the button doesn't exist yet, so the script can't bind the click event.

Comment: The problem happens because the $ (document).ready fires before the page rendering, this probably happens because the script thinks that the page is already ready, since you just changed the document content with javascript. I've improved my answer to better show you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... it worked for me... you need to add the jquery.min.js library link in the second page.

```
<html>
<header>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> //add it
</script>

</header>

<body >
    B
    <button id="backButton">Back</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/B.js"></script> // add the line here

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't help.
I see the following warning on the console 


login.js:14 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.